# Getting the current location using Google Maps API flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

I have added Google Maps to my app but I want to have it display the user's current location when it is first displayed.

I found code here on this site here: [Current location on the google maps (Flutter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73490833/current-location-on-the-google-maps-flutter)

but I am getting an error when I run the code.

Here is my code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MapPropertySearchResults extends StatefulWidget {
  const MapPropertySearchResults({super.key});

  @override
  State<MapPropertySearchResults> createState() =>
      _MapPropertySearchResultsState();
}

class _MapPropertySearchResultsState extends State<MapPropertySearchResults> {
    late GoogleMapController mapController;

  late LatLng _currentPosition;
  bool _isLoading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getLocation();
  }

  getLocation() async {
    LocationPermission permission;
    permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();

    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    double lat = position.latitude;
    double long = position.longitude;

    LatLng location = LatLng(lat, long);

    setState(() {
      _currentPosition = location;
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Map'),
      ),
      body: _isLoading ? 
      const Center(child:CircularProgressIndicator()) : 
      GoogleMap(
        onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          target: _currentPosition,
          zoom: 16.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The execution stops in the platform_channel.dart file, which is not my file.

This is the error message in the platform_channel.dart file:
[image]

What am I doing wrong because this is the solution found in the other question I referenced above.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop the project and start again.

This means Android native code can't catch flutter's method request.